# How to add listener to the upload component of vaadin 14 When the X button is clicked

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mshOt.png)

When i want delete some file and upload another instead , i can not find the way to realize it since after i click the X button, The file of the background object always exists( When I upload two, delete one, and then upload another, there will be three file objects in the background.)
Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Q81.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq7Ri.png).
And the Upload Component do not have the listener of it.

Give me a way to get the exact file uploaded by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Vaadin 24.4, you can use a workaround like this:

```
        upload.getElement().executeJs(
                "this.addEventListener('file-remove', (e) => $0.$server.fileRemove(e.detail.file.name));",
                getElement());
```

and declare a `@ClientCallable` method `fileRemove` to remove a file with that name from your storage.